# How to get connected to an existing session of Spark

Tags: r, session, apache-spark, sparkr

I installed spark (`spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7`) locally with success.

Running spark from terminal was successful through the command below:

```
$ spark-shell
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/01/08 12:30:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/01/08 12:30:30 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Spark context Web UI available at http://127.0.0.20:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1483864221428).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

When I open a session of spark from R, it creates a new one. But, this session has another port which is normal: http://127.0.0.20:4040 for existing session and http://127.0.0.20:4041 for the new session.

What I am looking for is to get connected to the same session. To do so, I try to get connected based on this R code: `sparkR.session(master = "127.0.0.20:4040", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))`

Unfortunately, I got the error below. So, how to get connected the same instance?

Thanks

---

### The error:

```
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: /home/amine/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
Launching java with spark-submit command /home/amine/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit   --driver-memory "2g" sparkr-shell /tmp/RtmpAZktq6/backend_port194b83111ed 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/01/08 14:19:54 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/01/08 14:19:54 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
17/01/08 14:19:54 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: '127.0.0.20:4040'
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD$.createSparkContext(RRDD.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD.createSparkContext(RRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:40)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/01/08 14:19:54 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
17/01/08 14:19:54 ERROR RBackendHandler: createSparkContext on org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:40)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: '127.0.0.20:4040'
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD$.createSparkContext(RRDD.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD.createSparkContext(RRDD.scala)
    ... 36 more
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: '127.0.0.20:4040'
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD$.createSparkContext(RRDD.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD.createSparkContext(RRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible using plain Spark only. You can use:

- [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/).
- [Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/livy).

Both support shared context, each in its own way.

Also `master` and `driver` are two completely different things.

Comment: Thank you very much. These solutions seem to be working only on linux distributions. Can they be installed on windows ?

Comment: **PS**: I have not understood what do you mean by the `master` and `driver`. Can you give more details...

Comment: Zeppelin should work. Don't know about Livy. `master` is a resource manager. This is the url you pass as `master` argument. Driver is a particular application.  In local mode there is standalone master.